# Teradata - how to avoid multiple redistribution happening

Tags: teradata

I have the query below. Problem with this is redistribution of data multiple times.

I have tried join index, NUSI, didn't help to avoid redistribution.

Please advise to how could I do this query better. Thanks

`Document` and `Traveller_Name` have the following PI and indexes defined

```
PRIMARY INDEX ( Record_Locator ,Passenger_Tattoo )
INDEX DOC_IDX1 ( Record_Locator )
INDEX DOC_IDX2 ( Record_Locator ,PNR_Creation_TS )
INDEX DOC_IDX3 ( Family_Name );
```

`ITENARY_SEGMENT` has the following PI and indexes defined

```
PRIMARY INDEX ( Record_Locator ,Segment_Tattoo )
INDEX ITS_IDX1 ( Record_Locator )
INDEX ITS_IDX2 ( Record_Locator ,PNR_Creation_TS )
INDEX ITS_IDX3 ( Record_Locator ,Origin_City_Code ,Destination_Port_Code ,
Departure_Date ,Route_ID );
```

Regards
Suresh

```
sel  
AL1.bookingSystemCode ,
AL1.recordLocator , 
AL1.pnrCreationTimestamp 
FROM       
EDW_DB.TRAVELLER_NAME AL1 
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT   
    AL1.recordLocator , 
    AL1.passengerTattoo 
    FROM       EDW_DB.traveller_name AL1 
    WHERE    1=1  
        AND al1.familyName = ('JOHN')
        AND al1.givenName = ('CITIZEN')
    
    UNION   
    SELECT   
    d1.recordLocator , 
    d1.passengerTattoo 
    FROM       EDW_DB.DOCUMENT  AS D1
    WHERE   1=1  
        AND d1.givenNames = ('CITIZEN')
        AND d1.familyName = ('JOHN')
    
)   AS  t1 
    ON ( AL1.recordLocator = t1.recordLocator 
    AND AL1.passengerTattoo = t1.passengerTattoo 
) 

INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT  
    ITS.bookingSystemCode , 
    ITS.recordLocator , 
    ITS.pnrCreationTimestamp ,
    ITS.departureTimestampUtc, 
    ITS.segmentTattoo,
    ITS.pushSegCancellationReceived,
    ITS.segmentStatus
    FROM       
    EDW_DB.ITENARY_SEGMENT  AS  ITS 
    WHERE    
    1=1
        AND ( its.routeId IN ('EK414') 
        OR its.parentRouteId IN ('EK414')) 
        AND its.originCityCode = ('DXB')
        AND its.departureDate BETWEEN  DATE '2020-08-01' 
        AND DATE '2020-08-31'
        AND its.companyCode IN ('EK')
    
)  AS ITS     
    ON AL1.bookingSystemCode = ITS.bookingSystemCode 
    AND AL1.recordLocator = ITS.recordLocator
    AND AL1.pnrCreationTimestamp = ITS.pnrCreationTimestamp 

INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT  
    ITS1.bookingSystemCode , 
    ITS1.recordLocator , 
    ITS1.pnrCreationTimestamp ,
    ITS1.departureTimestampUtc 
    FROM       
    EDW_DB.ITENARY_SEGMENT  AS  ITS1 
    WHERE    
    1=1
        AND  Trim(its1.destinationPortCode) LIKE ANY ( '%%SYD',
    'MEL',
    'BNE',
    'OOL',
    'ADL',
    'DRW',
    'PER',
    'CBR%%')
        AND (its1.routeId IN ('EK414')
        OR its1.parentRouteId IN ('EK414')) 
        AND its1.arrivalDate BETWEEN  DATE '2020-08-01' 
        AND DATE '2020-08-31'
        AND its1.companyCode IN ('EK')
    
)  AS ITS1       
    ON AL1.bookingSystemCode = ITS1.bookingSystemCode 
    AND AL1.recordLocator = ITS1.recordLocator
    AND AL1.pnrCreationTimestamp = ITS1.pnrCreationTimestamp;
```

@dnoeth, thanks for following up on this. I was unable to paste the explain plan for some reason. So, I have attached as links here. Please let me know if you couldn't access.

[Explain plan[][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/skVf9.png)

[Explain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SLA05.png)

Comment: Without Explain it's hard to tell, but there seem to be lots of selective Where-conditions and the amount of rows should be small. Why is the redistibution bad, did you check QryLogStepsV?

Comment: With all those interim steps (derived tables),  a certain amount of redistribution is inevitable.

Comment: Well, estimated time based on Explain is 0.05 seconds. What's the actual runtime? If it's way slower, the execution details from dbc.QryLogStepsV are important to see the bad performing steps.